# Last index ofmMulti-dimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to get the last index of my array but i get that property 'name' is undefined. What is the correct approach to get the last index of my multi dimensional array?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr[0][i] = {
        name: i,
    }
}
alert(arr[0][arr[0].length - 1].name);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you initializing the `arr`?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that part to the code. Im usign var arr = {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `arr[0]` also.

```js
var arr = {};
arr[0] = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr[0][i] = {
    name: i
  }
}
console.log(arr);
alert(arr[0][arr[0].length - 1].name);
```

Comment: I was trying to do arr[0] = {} instead of arr[0] = []. Why was that a problem? But your solution worked.